# Recuperar child dentro do getKey

Tags: android, firebase

Eu tenho uma Recycler adapter com um populateViewHolder que quando clico pega a chave da child no firebase, no casso da imagem abaixo pega `KeGVDMcSt0v5HICwuUm`

```
  @Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(ChatViewHolder viewHolder, Chat model, int position) {
  final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
```

assim são as child

[image]
                                                
   
eu mando a chave para a outra atividade com `singleBlogIntent.putExtra"blog_id", post_key);`

e recupero com `mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("blog_id");`

só que eu preciso pegar o valor uid `hC7y1BKtAWTFR&zoXVkr3oYjLTS2` dentro dessa child.

Não sei explicar nos termos técnicos e muito menos se o titulo condiz com a pergunta ,  Agradeço a desde já.

**Atualização**

Eu pretendo recuperar desde modo, comparar o `uid` que no caso teria que ser o "blog_id" e pegar o usuário desde id na child  `Users`

```
   final String currentUserId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("blog_id");
   mDatabaseCurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
   mQueryCurrentUser = mDatabaseCurrentUser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserId)
```

Comment: Algo não ficou claro. Eu percebi a sua pergunta original perfeitamente. Mas a actualização me deixou baralhado. Pode explicar melhor essa última parte?